# Best way to recieve a webhook and send back http response with status code on ExpressionEngine (version 5.4)

Tags: php, api, rest, webhooks, expressionengine

I am not that familiar with Expression Engine and I want to know the best way to recieve and sendback response to the webhook sent to an endpoint I can setup in Expression Engine. Is it even possible? I tried writing code to recieve a POST request on a template I just created and testing a POST request results in a 403 error with "The form is expired. Please refresh and try again."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'll need to create a plugin or module, which lets you create a corresponding Action URL you can POST to, and in the plugin/module code you can receive the POST request and do what you want with it.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/models/action.html
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/modules.html

If you upgrade to EE6 there is a built in CLI tool to generate the base add-on files to get you started.

Comment: You should check out the forums, or better yet the Slack, where people are pretty active. https://expressionengine.com/forums https://expressionengine.com/blog/join-us-in-slack#join-us-on-slack

Comment: Oh great thanks! I temporarily solved this by using another independent endpoint from which I accessed the POST values but looks like I can update to this now.